# Finding a list or tuple within a .txt file containing a specified item

Tags: python

For example I have a .txt file containing something like this:

12345 ABC XYZ,
67890 DEF NIL,
34567 XCV KOL,

I want to take an input for example "ABC" and this will return a tuple containing all the values,
of the line containing "ABC"

I tried something like this:

```
entf = input("Please supply a file name:")
f = open(entf)
l = []
enti = input("item:")
for enti in f:
    l.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
```

This works but it shows everything in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the file name is `tmpfile` containing what you have given,

```
f = open('tmpfile','r')
x = f.read()
y = tuple(i for i in x.split(',') if 'ABC' in i)
print y
```

This will output : `('12345 ABC XYZ',)`

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the file? Or give show the exact contents of the file?

Comment: After each "," there is a new line. if that makes any difference

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference, i don't see why it doesnt work for you

Comment: 3, I made a mistake. each line is not separated by a "," if i put a "," after each line the program works

Comment: I changed x.split(",") to x.splitlines()

Comment: `x.split()` by default splits the string at `'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.findall(r"^.*?\b"+input()+"\b.*$",file.read())
```